# React-Redux: Aggrid's editable field changing state directly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, ag-grid

I am using AGGrid using react with redux, so inside one of my components I have:

```
<AGGrid React
  columnDefns={props.columnDefs}
  rowData = {props.rows}
  ....
</>
```

The props refer to the state of the component in which this AGGrid is in.
Some of my `columnDefns` are editable.

I discover that, when I edit those editable fields in the aggrid from the browser, it updates the `props.row` as well, without me doing anything else.

Is this the expected 'feature' of aggrid? Or is it not supposed to do that? (instead I have to have an `onChange` to each editable cell to update the state with the changed value?)

Comment: I have similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269113/aggrid-in-react-redux-app-is-modifying-underlying-data . Did you manage to solve it?