# How to access the nested property-by-name of the Javascript object when the object is accessed from the spread notation ...?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, ag-grid, spread-syntax

This https://stackoverflow.com/a/4255480/1375882is good answer about the use of bracked notation to access the properties of the Javascript object/array by the name and it also show examples how to access nested properties or elements from the nested arrays.

I am trying to use the same approach to access the properties/elements in the construction that uses spread ... operator, e.g.:

```
var foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: {x: 999, y:998, z: 997}};
var foo1 = {...foo,
               ['a']: 2,
               ['c']['y']: 1000,
            };

alert(foo1['c']['y']);
```

But this code does not compile - while the one-level access `['a']` works as expected, the nested access `['c']['y']` does not work with with spread (but it works outside spread) - the code simply does not compile, there are error messages about un-matched `{` and other obscure messages (e.g. in jsfiddle).

My question is - **how to access nested properties/elements within spread? Maybe other constructions that brackets are necessary?**

**Context:** I am trying to write general code that listend to the cell value changes in the AgGrid and accordingly updates the Redux store: grid displays the array or records and in my update code I should find the right record and the right cell within it - all this happens in Redux reduce with usually uses spread... for correct update of state, e.g. idiomatic code is:

```
case GET_INVOICES_SUCCESS: {
              return {...state,
                 invoiceDate: action.response.data.invoiceDate,
              }
            }
```

But I should be able to access the individual properties and nested propertes of the state here. This [agGrid in react + redux app is modifying underlying data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269113/aggrid-in-react-redux-app-is-modifying-underlying-data) is the code which I am trying to generalize.

So - you can see that **the use of spread... is not luxury for me, it is the best practice for use in Redux reducers** and that is why I have this question.

Comment: Although the answers you received are correct, it is not clear to me whether your "general example" code (the one with `foo` and `foo1`) actually matches the "real example" code of your reducer. It is impossible to tell for sure, without seeing the code for the initial sate, but if invoiceDate is a leaef of your state (`state.invoiceDate`), your reducer should be correct as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tasos and Nina for suggestions, but I specifically asked for the case when property is accessed by name and that is why the correct answer is this:

```
var foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: {x: 999, y:998, z: {aa: 5, bb: 6}}};
var foo1 = {...foo,
               ['a']: 2,
               ['c']: {...foo['c'], 
                    ['y']: 1000, 
               },
               ['c']: {...foo['c'],
                    ['z']: {...foo['c']['z'],
                          ['bb']: 777,
                           }
               }
            };

alert(foo1['c']['z']['bb']);
```

I don't know whether I should accept my own answer because without input from the previous answer there would not be my answer.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it's the most suitable solution to the problem in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You could separate the wanted nested property with an own spreading.

```js
const
    foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: { x: 999, y: 998, z: 997 } },
    foo1 = { ...foo,
        a: 2,
        c: { ...foo.c, y: 1000 },
    };

console.log(foo1['c']['y']);
console.log(foo1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the spread operator for the nested properties as well:

```
var foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: {x: 999, y:998, z: 997}};
var foo1 = {...foo,
               a: 2,
               c: { ...foo.c, y: 1000 },
            };

alert(foo1.c.y);
```

Also, you don't need the square brackets if the property name is not a variable.